# Passing array to Start-Job as a parameter

Tags: multithreading, powershell, parameters, parameter-passing, start-job

After a long time reading here, I'm finally at a point where I needed to register. So hallo from my side.
I'm currently working on a programm to retrieve informations out of the Windows EventLogs. To parse the logs and export them to a csv file I'm using the standard Windows Powershell-Tools which works fine for me. To speed up the process, I decided that I'm going to use multithreading. Each Log get it's own Thread to retrieve the informations in a faster manner.
However in doing so, I'm currently stuck and don't know how to continue any more.

In a few of my function I wanna use an array of EventIds like `$evtid= @(4624,4648)`, which gonna be passed alongside other parameters. Unfortunately I haven't any luck with passing this array as a parameter, which results in an incomplete run of the job. The desired output would be a filtered `.csv`-file, but the output I get is just an empty file. It seems like the job starts running and is marked as `completed` very quickly, because I'm getting over a following `Get-Job | Wait-Job`-statement. I strongly believe that the passing is the problem, because another function which doesn't filter for this ID's and therefore have no arrays to pass, work perfectly fine.

Here the function in question and the variables I use for the EventIDs:

```
#defines EventIDs and imports WinEventData
$systemid=@(7035,7034,7040) 
$loc = Get-Location
"$($loc)\*.psm1" | gci  | Import-Module

#Starts the job and is intended to filter the EventID with -FilterHashtable
$JobSysFiltered= Start-Job -ScriptBlock{param ($evtmax,$system,$systemid,$systemstart,$systemend,$systemcsv)
 Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents $evtmax -FilterHashtable @{Path=$system;ID=$systemid;starttime=$systemstart;
endtime=$systemend} |  Get-WinEventData | Select-Object RecordId,Id,TimeCreated,
                              TaskDisplayName,
                              Task,
                              ProviderName,
                              ProviderId,
                              LogName,
                              MachineName,
                              UserId,
                              e_ServiceName,
                              e_ImagePath,
                              e_ServiceType,
                              e_StartType,
                              e_AccountName,
                              Message     | 
                Export-Csv $systemcsv -Delimiter ';'} -ArgumentList ($evtmax,$system,(,$systemid),$systemstart,$systemend,$systemcsv)
```

The stuff I found during my research doesn't worked so far. Already tried to use a `[int[]]`-Syntax in the `param`-Section, which doesn't helped. If the problem is somewhere else to be found, I would be open for any suggestions. Appreciate any help and tipps on that, because I'm out of ideas right now, but don't wanna go back to a non-multithreading script if possible.

Comment: What is `Get-WinEventData` and considering it is a custom function, how does your job knows what that function is?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon `Get-WinEventData` is indeed an custom function which I imported as a module. It is retrieving XML-Informations out of the EventData-Section and definitely works. Using it in my other Parts and it works fine. Great Tool for Eventlogs and you can find the Module over here
[on Github](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PowerShell/blob/master/Get-WinEventData.ps1)

Comment: Ok so, first of, you need to pass that function in your jobs scriptblock. Your current scope is not the same as your jobs scope. It would be useful if you could add all the errors you're getting when you receive-job.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon The errors or better non-errors are part of the problem. It is running, but not with the desired output. It seems like it starts the Job, but in the end I'm getting a empty `.csv`-File back. I assume that it does the first part of the job and then mark it as `Completed`. The following code involves a `Get-Job | Wait-Job`-Statement, so it must be an logical finish. What I don't really figured out is, where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of sleep I finally found a workaround for the problem, which I wanna provide to people who are having a similar problem. Since it wasn't possible to pass multiple parameters which included an array, I just joined them together in another array. It seems to be important to cast the IDs inside the job with `[int[]]`, since the `-FilterHashtable` can't handle the PSObject.
If you wanna use an parameter in one of your jobs, just call them over there indexes. However I couldn't make it work with the output path, so it seems to be necessary to create a variable. If there is a special reason for that, I would be glad for an explanation.

Here a little sample code:

1. Define array with parameters
   ===============================

   `$variablearraysys= @($evtmax,$system,$systemid,$systemstart,$systemend,$systemcsv)`
2. Use elements of array via index
   ==================================

   ```
    $JobSysFiltered= Start-Job -ScriptBlock{param ($variablearraysys) 

    $csv=$variablearraysys[5]

    Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents $variablearraysys[0] -FilterHashtable @{Path=$variablearraysys[1];ID=[int[]]$variablearraysys[2];starttime=$variablearraysys[3];endtime=$variablearraysys[4]} |  Get-WinEventData | 
                 Select-Object RecordId,Id,TimeCreated,
                              TaskDisplayName,
                              Task,
                              ProviderName,
                              ProviderId,
                              LogName,
                              MachineName,
                              Message     | 
                Export-Csv $csv} -ArgumentList (,$variablearraysys)
   ```

Note that it is also important to use a `(,$variable)`-Syntax when you pass your array to `-ArgumentList`. Otherwise it will not use the complete array. Hope that helps with future problems of this kind.